# Is there a console for PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, console, phantomjs

I found this on github: https://github.com/gr2m/phantomjs-console

But it is a bit crazy, having to write commands in a file, on one line only, which is then read, and deleted, and the output being in the terminal.

I want a console like...

```
$ phantomjs --console
phantom> console.log(typeof $)
[Object Function]
phantom> console.log("happy days")
happy days
phantom>
```

Is there anything like this?

### EDIT: Starting to understand why they did it in such a crazy way...

From PhantomJS-Node: https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node

> ### No really, how does it work?
>
> I will answer that question with a question.
>   How do you communicate with a process that doesn't support
>   shared memory, sockets, FIFOs, or standard input?
>
> Well, there's one thing PhantomJS does support, and that's opening
>   webpages. In fact, it's really good at opening web pages. So we
>   communicate with PhantomJS by spinning up an instance of ExpressJS,
>   opening Phantom in a subprocess, and pointing it at a special webpage
>   that turns socket.io messages into `alert()` calls. Those `alert()` calls
>   are picked up by Phantom and there you go!
>
> The communication itself happens via James Halliday's fantastic [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode)
>   library, which fortunately works well enough when combined with
>   [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to run straight out of PhantomJS's pidgin Javascript
>   environment.
>
> If you'd like to hack on phantom, please do! You can run the tests
>   with cake test or npm test, and rebuild the coffeescript/browserified
>   code with cake build. You might need to `npm install -g coffeescript`
>   for cake to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an interactive mode (REPL) since [version 1.5](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.5.html) almost a year ago. You just need to launch PhantomJS without any argument and it will immediately start in [REPL mode](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/REPL).

Comment: Now you mentioned it, it is actually clearly documented in the help on the command line... `Without any argument, PhantomJS will launch in interactive mode (REPL).` I don't understand why I could not find that info before.

Comment: And it seems a bug in the REPL prevents pages opening... so back to my hackish solution for now...

Comment: REPL can't open pages...?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I ended up writing a wrapper script for the console script I originally linked to: https://github.com/gr2m/phantomjs-console

It is a messy way of doing it, but actually works exactly as I want. Turns out, that phantomjs has plans to handle stdin/stdout but it is not yet implemented. When it is implemented, this crazy method of interacting will become obsolete, and a new, simple script will be able to act as console.

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee

sys = require "sys"
fs = require "fs"

# stdin = process.openStdin()
# stdin.addListener "data", (d)-> console.log "you entered: [" + d.toString().substring(0, d.length-1) + "]"

readline = require "readline"

spawn = require("child_process").spawn
phantom = spawn("phantomjs", ["phantom_console.coffee", "http://local/"])

rl = readline.createInterface process.stdin, process.stdout
rl.setPrompt 'phantom> '
rl.prompt()

rl.on 'line', (line)->
  if line == "exit"
    phantom.kill()
    rl.close()
  else
    fs.writeFile ".command.js", line
  # rl.prompt()

rl.on 'close', ->
  phantom.kill()
  process.exit(0)

phantom.stdout.on "data", (data) ->
  console.log data+''
  rl.prompt()

phantom.stderr.on "data", (data) ->
  console.log "\nstderr: " + data
  rl.prompt()

phantom.on "exit", (code) ->
  console.log "child process exited with code " + code
```